# Why did this user's reputation score drop to 1?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

The user [SS-3.1415926535897932384626433](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931/ss-3-1415926535897932384626433) has 17 Gold badges & countless other silver & bronze badges. He had a high reputation the last time I checked. Why did all of a sudden it reduced to 1. Did he delete his account & create a new one? But if that is the case why are all his badges intact

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91627/why-do-suspended-users-have-a-reputation-of-one

Comment: The top line on the linked user page should actually give pretty strong hint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This user is presently [suspended](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

When their suspension ends, their reputation score will automatically be reinstated and recalculated if their answers and questions have been up or down - voted.